# C++ - Undefined reference to "sodium_init"

Tags: c++, cryptography, codelite, libsodium, nacl-cryptography

I am attempting to make a testing application using **libsodium**, however I am getting the error:

```
main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sodium_init'
```

I ran the following commands to install in as the root user.

```
$ ./configure
$ make && make check
$ make install
```

This the code that is having the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sodium.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (sodium_init() == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("libsodium had no issues!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using **CodeLite** as my IDE, and my C++ compiler options are the following:

```
-g;-O0;-Wall;-lsodium
```

The options were default and I added `-lsodium` to the list.

Attempting to compile `main.cpp` directly from the terminal with the following command `g++ -lsodium main.cpp` throws the same error.

Could someone please help me with my issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Libraries for linking are searched in order, so you need to place the libraries *after* your local translation units:

```
g++ main.cpp -lsodium
```

In your IDE, make sure you add `-lsodium` as a *linker* argument.